# How do I validate multiple input fields in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to validate name, email and zip code on a button click, but it's showing only last error message, not specific to the field. I am writing this code in JavaScript & jquery. Any help appreciated.

```
if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "You valid First Name .";
    document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
    return false;
}

if (!ck_name.test(lname)) {
    errors[errors.length] = "You valid last name .";
    document.getElementById("errorlastname").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You haven't included near enough information for anyone to help you. Give a reduced version of your code, and the error that you're getting.

Comment: if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
  errors[errors.length] = "You valid First Name .";
  document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
  return false;
 }
 if (!ck_name.test(lname)) {
  errors[errors.length] = "You valid last name .";
 document.getElementById("errorlastname").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
 return false;
}   i m using above code to valide the firstname and last name. i m giving wrong first name and last name. but error msg is prompting for the last name only.

Comment: Edit the code into your question and format it so it's actually readable.

Comment: i think there is problem in return false, but how i resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you return a value in a function, none of the code following the return statement is executed. Because of this, rather than returning false after each validation error, you should should only return true/false after you've performed all of your desired validations.

```
if (!ck_name.test(name)) {
    errors.push("You valid First Name.");
    document.getElementById("errorname").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
}

if (!ck_name.test(lname)) {
    errors.push("You valid last name.");
    document.getElementById("errorlastname").innerHTML = "You must enter a username";
}

return (errors.length == 0);
```